# What's the difference between an if statement and an if statement for validity check/variable guard check?

Tags: c, if-statement

This isn't a straight up coding question, there's no specific code involved. It's more of a general question that I've been struggling with to understand.

What is the difference between an if statement, and an if statement for validity check/variable guard check?

I ask this because my instructor told us to write a function without using if statements(except for validity check/variable guard check) and I'm a little confused on the difference between them. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no specific difference in the statement itself, only in the purpose for which you use that statement.

If you add a conditional to see if the input parameters are valid to your specification (say, indexes are non-negative, and fall within the range of your array) then your instructor says he would accept your solution. If, on the other hand, you use conditionals to compute the output of your function, then the instructor would not consider your solution acceptable.

Note that C provides an alternative way of ensuring the validity of your parameters - namely, the [`assert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert) functionality. There is no explicit `if`, but the program would break if a condition is violated:

```
void setArrayElementSafe(int *array, size_t size, size_t index, int newValue) {
    assert(index < size); // End the program if index is outside bounds
    array[index] = newValue;
}
```

An easy test to see if your program would be acceptable or not is to see if you could replace all its `if`s with `assert`s (you don't have to actually do it; just go through your code and make sure that it's possible).

Comment: So something like if (function(x, y) > 10) etc..., would be unacceptable right? As opposed to something like if (result > 10) etc..?

Comment: @Karen I do not know the specifics, but it looks like both of these would be invalid (unless the purpose of checking `if (result > 10)` is to report an error).

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference, there is only one kind of `if` statement. The condition is on the structure of your program, not on the specific "type" of `if` statement. The instructor is requiring that you don't introduce unnecessary `if` statements, except to check a "guard" variable, so presumably there is a process where by you can solve your task with only that use of `if`.

Answer (score 1):

I take it to mean that you comply with your instructors rules if you can remove all the `if` statements from your code and the code will still work correctly provided you give it correct input. In other words, the only `if` statements you're allowed are those to check for preconditions and assumptions, but are *not* part of the algorithmic logic of your code.

Answer (score 0):

No difference at all. `if` statements are meant to be validity check. There is no any type or class for `if` statements.